# Perl's DBD::mysql -- installation conflict

Tags: perl, installation, perl-module

Attempting to install the Perl module `DBD::mysql` on Windows 7

From the Windows command line I executed

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBD::mysql'
```

Which downloaded and uncompressed the file -- **then gave me this ERROR:**

```
  CPAN.pm: Going to build C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.018.tar.gz

Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
C:\PROGRA~1\MySQL\MYSQLS~1.1\bin\MYSQLA~1.EXE: connect to server at 'localhost'
failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
Problem running C:\PROGRA~1\MySQL\MYSQLS~1.1\bin\MYSQLA~1.EXE - aborting ...
Warning: No success on command[C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site
]
```

Guessing the issue is that MySQL's root user has a password, but what's not clear is how I resolve the issue.

Questions, feedback, requests -- just comment, thanks!!

**----------
UPDATE (1):** RE: force install DBD::mysql

```
cpan> force install DBD::mysql
Running install for module 'DBD::mysql'
Running make for C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.018.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\Perl\cpan\build\DBD-mysql-4.018-A
1T8Uh
  'C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site' returned status 256, won't
 make
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
```

Comment: What vendor are you using for Perl on Windows?  What have you tried in the installation section (http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.018/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#INSTALLATION) of the docs that hasn't worked?

Comment: @Robert P: Thanks, that worked -- posted it as an answer, feel free to repost my notes as your answer, I'll delete mine, and select you as the answer. Again, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on "Robert P" comment, I checked the install guide for [installing DBD::MySQL in ActivePerl on Win32](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.018/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#WIN32_INSTALLATION); on 64, but doesn't appear to have mattered.

Command that did the job was:

```
ppm install DBD::mysql
```

Comment: You should have said which version of Perl you are using: ActivePerl or StrawberryPerl.

Comment: @dolmen: Hide sight is 20-20... didn't even know ActivePerl or StrawberryPerl was doing something different; also, notice not one of the answers stated anything about their solution not working for ActivePerl, or only for XYZ.

Answer (score 2):

On other platforms, the build process runs the mysql_config command to get necessary information about the mysql installation without need of a user and password; on win32, if you have a mysql_config command, you have to explicitly tell Makefile.PL about it with a `--mysql_config yourpathname` parameter.  If you don't, it looks for the mysqladmin program and uses its location to determine as much as it can but runs `mysqladmin version` to get the mysql version.  You can provide a user/password for it to be able to do this using --testuser and --testpassword parameters to Makefile.PL.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've got round this in the past is a forced install.  It always feels like a bodge but I haven't been able to find a better way.

Open up a CPAN shell:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'shell'
```

Then do a force install

```
force install DBD::mysql
```

quit gets you back out of the shell.

Comment: Thanks, attempt "force install DBD::mysql" during a CPAN session -- and it didn't work. I've posted the output in the questions description under "UPDATE (1) RE: force install DBD::mysql" -- if there's something I'm doing wrong, just let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as ysth said , maybe try this :

```
cd  C:\Perl\cpan\build\DBD-mysql-4.018-A
```

and run

```
perl Makefile.PL  --testuser validuser  --testpassword validpassword
```

and then try to make - make test - make install,
or its equivalents on windows

Comment: `look DBD::mysql` in the cpan shell will fetch and unpack the distribution and put you at a command prompt in the unpacked directory